# How do I merge adjacent time spans with the same data value?

Tags: c#, date, csv, time, bigdata

I have a file with comma separated values (CSV), that have this format:

```
26/09/2015,GROUP_1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12345.006,12345.006,27469.005,27469.005,27983.005,27983.005,28081.005,0,0,0,28105.005,28105.005,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Every number represents the work hours over an interval of 15 minutes, over the range 8:00 am - 8:00 pm.  The first start time is `08:00:00`) and the last start time will be `19:45:00`; there are 49 "columns" of data.

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12345.006,12345.006,27469.005,27469.005,27983.005,27983.005,28081.005,0,0,0,28105.005,28105.005,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

The date will be the date when the "event" happened and it's the date on the data. But I need to get the values that are the same and specify a time range. For example, those first two non-zero values are the same:

```
12345.006,12345.006
```

These start at 10:30 and 10:45; I need to merge these and report 12345 hours for the time span 10:30 - 11:00 am.

I read the file; I have those values as an array, and the problem I'm having is how to "group" the same values into the appropriate time ranges.

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2015,08,05);
DateTime finisDahte = new DateTime(2015,08,05);
int column = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    //timerange start with every 15 minutes by column
    if (column >= 2)
    {
        if (data[i] != "0")
        {
            //Getting rid of decimals, they are not neccesary and that's how the file have it, I dont know why
            if (data[i].Contains('.'))
            {
                data[i] = data[i].Substring(0, data[i].LastIndexOf('.'));

            }

            //we check if there is a next index to compare the same value
            if ((i + 1) <= totalElementos)
            {

                var nextElem = data[i + 1];
                if (nextElem != "0")
                {
                    nextElem.Substring(0, nextElem.LastIndexOf('.'));
                }
                else
                {
                    //the is no next element... something here
                }

                //CRUCIAL PART: if the current index it's the same as the next one, it means they share the time range
                if (data[i] == nextElem)
                {
                    //the same index as the next one
                    //I need to identify when it's the first time I'm comparing a value with the next one, so I can set a start date
                    //I need to sum the total amount of time ranges for every repetition they have and save when the value start and when the value is different (so it's a new value)
                }
                else
                {
                    //it's not the same index, so technically the finishdate will be set here?
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //there is not more indexes, so finishdate will be here
            }

        }

    }

    //column++;
}
```

Hope I could explain. Thanks

Comment: Easy with code I provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate a class like the code below.  I changed the date to US format for testing.  The code below reads from a string using StringReader and when reading from a file use StreamReader instead.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<DataSample> samples = new List<DataSample>();
            string data = "9/26/2015,GROUP_1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12345.006,12345.006,27469.005,27469.005,27983.005,27983.005,28081.005," +
                          "0,0,0,28105.005,28105.005,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0\n";
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(data);
            string inputline = "";

            while ((inputline = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                string[] dataArray = inputline.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(dataArray[0]);
                startDate = startDate.AddHours(8);

                DateTime timeCounter = startDate;
                string groupName = dataArray[1];

                for (int i = 2; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (dataArray[i] != "0")
                    {
                        DataSample newSample = new DataSample();
                        samples.Add(newSample);
                        newSample.name = groupName;
                        newSample.time = timeCounter;
                        newSample.value = double.Parse(dataArray[i]);
                    }
                    timeCounter = timeCounter.AddMinutes(15);
                }
            }

            var groupByValue = samples.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.value)
                .ToList();

            foreach (var group in groupByValue)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Value : {0}, Times : {1}", group.Key.ToString(), string.Join(",",group.Select(x => x.time.ToString())));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
    public class DataSample
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public DateTime time { get; set; }
        public double value { get; set; }
    }

}
​
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem with your code is that I need to identify even the 0's as a timerange, so the first value must be 9/26/2015 10:00:00 to 9/26/2015 10:30:00. I want to ignore the 0. I'll study your code to come with a solution

Comment: Update code.  Used AddHours and AddMinutes to make the code more understandable.  There was nothing wrong with original code.  You just didn't specify that you wanted to ignore zero values.  Just added a simply if statement,

Comment: Well yeah when I posted the comment I realized few moments later that what that simple. Anyway thanks for the advice every day I learn something new. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not a coding service; you need to go a little farther.  You've done a good job of outlining your algorithm; now, you should put in a few print statements to track the operation of your code.  Do the loops and if statements give you the control flow you expected?  A good way to do this is to put your comments into print statements, such as in your last inside comment:

```
print "there is not more indexes, so finishdate will be here"
```

Also print the loop index, values you found, etc.

Once you have corrected any flow problems there, start filling in the comment-only blocks with useful code, a few lines or one block at a time.

When you hit a specific problem, post your code and the actual output.  That's where StackOverflow is designed to help you.

---

In the meantime, I'd like to g a change to your outer loop.  Let it be driven as a while loop, so you can freely advance your index as needed.  Right now, you're keeping two variables for almost the same purpose: i and column.  Instead, use just one, something like:

```
column = 0
while (column < data.Length)
    // Find all of the indices with the same consecutive value
    finish_index = column;
    while data[start_column] = data[finish_index+1]
        finish_index++;
    // You now have the range of work slots to merge.
    printf "Time slots %d - %d have %d work hours", column, finish_index, int(data[column])

    column = finish_index+1
}
```

You will still have to convert column numbers to times: 15 minutes * column + 8:00am.  I've also left out a few intermediate nice steps, but I think that you already have them in your comments.

Does this get you moving?

Comment: I will follow your advice and see what I can get